# Handles Me.Event vs Handles MyBase.Event

Tags: vb.net, events

```
Class BaseClass
    Public Event MyEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Class
Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass
    Sub DerivedClassEventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MyEvent
        'Do something here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is there any difference between the above and using `Handles MyBase.MyEvent`, as per the [guidance here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172877.aspx) under the heading **Handling Events Inherited From a Base Class**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this simple example, there's little difference.  You could argue that by using `Handles MyBase...` that it's clearer for future readers of the code to know where the event comes from.

One potential reason for preferring one or the other is in the (unusual) situation of creating an event with the same name in your derived class - the difference between `Me` and `MyBase` allows you to be specific as to which event you're handling:

```
Class BaseClass
    Public Event MyEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Class
Class DerivedClass
    Inherits BaseClass

    Public Shadows Event MyEvent(sender As Object, e As SomeOtherEventArgs)

    Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MyEvent

    End Sub

    Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As SomeOtherEventArgs) Handles Me.MyEvent

    End Sub
End Class
```